# Deleting dataset attachment in Socrata with API

Tags: python, socrata, soda

I'm working on a python script that will: 
1) pull GIS metadata from an enterprise database
2) parse the metadata from XML to plain text
3) attach the text files to the corresponding published datasets in Socrata (which are published monthly)
4) The script will also be run monthly, so that any schema changes in the enterprise dataset are reflected in the attached plain text metadata files on Socrata.

I've been able to successfully attach the text metadata files to published Socrata datasets using some code found [here](https://github.com/codeforamerica/socrata-python/blob/master/Socrata.py).  The problem is, each time the script is run, an additional attachment is added.  I would like to either delete the existing attachment and add a new one, or overwrite the existing attachment with the contents of the new one.

I've done a fair amount of research on this, and can't seem to find any documentation for managing attachments using the Socrata API.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please show your code!?

Comment: And in addition, an example dataset I could take a look at the metadata for.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this one out.  Had to alter a few lines to empty out the attachments in the attach_file function in the [Socrata Python](https://github.com/codeforamerica/socrata-python) library  from:

```
def attach_file(self, filename):
    metadata = self.metadata()
    if not metadata.has_key('attachments'):
        metadata['attachments'] = []
```

to:

```
def attach_file(self, filename):
    metadata = self.metadata()
    metadata['attachments'] = []    #empty out metadata, regardless of existing metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the same API and was able to replace attachments using the following code:

```
def attach_file(self, filename, clear_metadata):
    metadata = self.metadata()
    if not metadata.has_key('attachments'):
        metadata['attachments'] = []
    # if the user wants to clear all existing attachments on dataset
    if clear_metadata:
        metadata['attachments'] = []
    response = self.multipart_post('/assets', filename)
    if not response.has_key('id'):
        print "Error uploading file to assets service: no ID returned: %s" % response
        return
    attachment = {'blobId': response['id'],
        'name': response['nameForOutput'],
        'filename': response['nameForOutput']}
    metadata['attachments'].append(attachment)
    self._request("/views/%s.json" % self.id, 'PUT', {'metadata':metadata})

def multipart_post(self, url, filename, field='file'):
    print("Running multipart_post")
    authBase64 = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (self.username, self.password)).replace('\n', '')

    datagen, headers       = multipart_encode({field: open(filename, "rb")})
    headers['X-App-Token'] = self.app_token
    headers['Authorization'] = "Basic %s" % authBase64
    print("url=" + url)
    request = Request("%s%s" % (self.url, url), datagen, headers)
    print(str(Request))
    response = urlopen(request).read()
    return json.loads(response)
```